# How can i extract URLs from docx file using python?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx

packages like **python docx** is ineffective in this case as it is used in creating and updating of Docx files.
Even if i get the full text, i can make some algorithm to extract links from that.
need help!

Answer (score 0):

If all of your links start with `http://` or `www.`, you could use a regular expression. From this post, said regular expression would be `\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b`

If you are using Python 3, you might try:

```
import re

doc = '...' # use PythonDocx to put the text in here
matches = re.search('\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b',doc)
if matches:
   print(matches(0))
```

Source: Python Documentation

If this is correct, this will locate all text within `doc` that starts with `http://`, `https://`, or `www.` and print them.

**Update:** whoops, wrong solution

From the python-docx documentation, here is a working solution:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document("foobar.docx")
doc = '' # only use if you want the entire document
for paragraph in document.paragraphs
   text = paragraph.text
   # with text, run your algorithms on it, paragraph by paragraph. if you want the whole thing:
   doc += text
# now run your algorithm on text
```

My Python is a bit rusty, so I might have made an error.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering !
but if you read my question carefully , actually i am having problem with that 'put the text in here' part . i can design some algorithm afterwards myself.
i would be glad if you can help me in that.